# how can I sum by a group in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<football xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="football originalfootball.xsd">
    <teams>
        <team>
            <name>Jets</name>
            <city>New York</city>
            <stadium>Giants Stadium</stadium>
        </team>
        <team>
            <name>Giants</name>
            <city>New York</city>
            <stadium>Giants Stadium</stadium>
        </team>
        <team>
            <name>Bills</name>
            <city>Buffalo</city>
            <stadium>Wilson Stadium</stadium>
        </team>
    </teams>
    <scores>
        <score>
            <home>
                <competitor>Jets</competitor>
                <points>20</points>
            </home>
            <visitor>
                <competitor>Giants</competitor>
                <points>7</points>
            </visitor>
        </score>
        <score>
            <home>
                <competitor>Bills</competitor>
                <points>10</points>
            </home>
            <visitor>
                <competitor>Jets</competitor>
                <points>17</points>
            </visitor>
        </score>
    </scores>
</football>
```

I want to get the sum of points for each team.

I've tried with `sum(//competitor[.=//name]/../points)` but it did not work.

I want the teams that have beaten the Giants.

Any ideas about this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum the points of a specific team, you can do:

```
sum(//score/*[competitor='Jets']/points)
```

In XPath 2.0 you can list all teams and their points like:

```
for $team in //teams/team/name
return concat($team, ': ', sum(//score/*[competitor=$team]/points))
```

To find the teams that have beaten the Giants

XPath 1.0

```
//score/*[points > ../*[competitor='Giants']/points]/competitor
```

XPath 2.0

```
//score/*[number(points) > ../*[competitor='Giants']/points/number()]/competitor
```

---

The problem with your query is the following part:

```
//competitor[.=//name]
```

For the given document, this is effectively the same as `//competitor` as for each `<competitor>` element there is a `<name>` element with the same value, so the predicate always evaluates to true. This means it sums up all points for all competitors.